# Efficient code for saving data to an ArrayList

Tags: java, xml, string, arraylist

My console outputs year tags from an XML file like this

```
2020
2019
1997
2017
2019
2017 (...)
```

From that data I want to save every different year in an ArrayList for example:

```
Years found on file: 2020 , 2019 , 1997 , 2017
```

I've tried a lot of things but none of them seems to be working. I'm trying to figure out a solution with that code below:

```
public class Publications {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("dblp-2020-04-01.xml");
        FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(fileStream);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(input);
        String line;
        ArrayList<String> publicationsList = new ArrayList<String>();
        int i = 0;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            Publications publ = new Publications();
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<year>(.+?)</year>", Pattern.DOTALL);
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
            if (matcher.find()) {
                String year = matcher.group(1);
                if (publicationsList.size() == 0) {
                    publicationsList.add(year);
                }else{
                    for(String publications1 : publicationsList){
                        if(!(publications1.contains(year))){
                            publicationsList.add(year);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //READING TEST
        for (String publications1 : publicationsList){
            System.out.println(publications1);
        }
    }
}
```

Errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:1042)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:996)
    at Publications.main(Publications.java:26)
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) with [`LinkedHashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) and duplicates will automatically be ignored, while order of inserted values are still retained.

Also, this is the year 2020, so you should use the NIO.2 API and the try-with-resources statement, both added in Java 7 back in 2011. That will help fix the issue with you not closing the file stream.

This is what your code should look like:

```java
Set<String> publicationYears = new LinkedHashSet<>();
try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("dblp-2020-04-01.xml"))) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<year>(.+?)</year>", Pattern.DOTALL);
    for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null; ) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            String year = matcher.group(1);
            publicationYears.add(year);
        }
    }
}
//READING TEST
for (String year : publicationYears){
    System.out.println(year);
}
```

---

Of course, since you're reading an XML file, it would be much better to **use an XML parser**, e.g. StAX:

```java
Set<String> publicationYears = new LinkedHashSet<>();
try (InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("dblp-2020-04-01.xml"))) {
    XMLStreamReader xml = XMLInputFactory.newFactory().createXMLStreamReader(in);
    while (xml.hasNext()) {
        xml.next();
        if (xml.getEventType() == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT) {
            if (xml.getLocalName().equals("year")) {
                String year = xml.getElementText();
                publicationYears.add(year);
            }
        }
    }
}
```